# How to store two or more images in server folder with file stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filestream

I want to upload 3 images to my node.js server. I send those 3 images as array of byte64 from my client side. Since it's async function how to do it one after the other without doing one by one. Is there any way to implement while loop or for loop but the one that will wait for one writing to end so it can start another one if the first pass without errors? Since its not hard to do it one by one when its only 3 images, but if there is 10 or more it would be hell to do each file Writing as callback from previous writing.
Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly. So it's an async function but you want the upload cycle to be in some sort of loop. So you can check if "image 1" is uploaded correctly and then start to upload "image 2" ect. right? You should post some code on how you handle things at the back-end currently.

Comment: Yes, one after the another. I saw something with promises.all, l will try that tomorrow since l am done for today, but if you have any solution in what way that could also be done it would be great. Currently in my back-end l have solution for handling single image, and that works perfectly since l manage response in callback, but with multiple images that should be saved it would be callback hell for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fs.promises` for a promise alternative of fs. Then you can use `Promise.all()` to run all the promises.

An example would be:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const stuffToWrite = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

// Create an async function
(async () => {
    await Promise.all(stuffToWrite.map((value, index) => fs.writeFile(`${index}.txt`, value)));
    console.log("Done!")
})();
```

This will create 3 files, those being 0.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt. You can change this up to match what you want.

According to the docs, Promise.all has a "fast-fail" feature, where if one fails, then it'll reject. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply and help. I did it like this in my node.js after your comment. I did not used it as async function but only like this. And I want to ask if its possible to use .then and .catch as I did. I mean this works but is it how its done to get response after file stream finish writing all files?

```
Promise.all(
              images.map((value, index) =>
                fs.promises.writeFile(
                  getPath(index),
                  value.base64,
                  "base64",
                  (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    } else {
                      console.log("done");
                    }
                  }
                )
              )
            )
              .then(() => {
                res.status(200).send({ message: "data saved" });
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(404).send({ message: "something went wrong" });
              });
```